# Let $A,B\subseteq A \times A$ be binary relations. If $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is symmetric, then $A \cup B$ is symmetric.

Tags: integration

The proof that I came with was the following:

Let $c=(x,y) \in A \cup B$. If $c \in A$, then $c$ is symmetric because $A$ is symmetric. If $c\in  B$, then $c$ is symmetric because $B$ is symmetric.

Then, $c$ is symmetric, and so $A \cup B$ is symmetric. Is this correct and enough?

Comment: The symbol $C$ has not been defined.  Furthermore, I would caution against using the same symbol, $A$, to denote both the underlying set and one of the binary relations.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but it could be much better phrased.  How I would rephrase the question and answer:

Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ both be symmetric relations over the set $A$.  Then the relation $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$ is also symmetric.

*Proof:* Suppose that $(x,y)\in \mathcal{A}\cup \mathcal{B}$.  Without loss of generality, suppose it is the case that $(x,y)\in\mathcal{A}$.  Since $\mathcal{A}$ is symmetric, then $(y,x)\in\mathcal{A}$ as well and therefore is also an element of $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$, thus proving that $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$ is symmetric. $\square$

---

Note the difference in symbols used, $\mathcal{A}$ vs $A$.  If you don't have access to script fonts, then perhaps use entirely different letters like $R,S$ to denote the relations, or change the underlying set to be $X$.  Note also that I didn't bother naming the ordered tuple and did not call the tuple itself "symmetric."

Note also the use of the phrase ["Without Loss of Generality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) which lets you skip proving additional separate cases in a proof in the event that their proofs are identical in nature to earlier cases.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've overloaded the symbol $A$ and not defined what $C$ is, I will have to make a few guesses to be able to piece together what exactly what you meant, but here's my best attempt at an answer:

Rather than calling the underlying set $A$, let us call it $S$. Let $A,B \subseteq S\times S$ be binary relations. We wish to show that if $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is symmetric, then $A\cup B$ is symmetric.

Suppose $(x,y) \in A\cup B$. Then $(x,y) \in A$ or $(x,y)\in B$. We may unpack this by cases.

Case 1:
We suppose $(x,y)\in A$. Then $ (y,x)\in A$ since $A$ is symmetric, and hence $(y,x) \in A\cup B$ and we are done.

Case 2: We suppose $(x,y)\in B$. Then $(y,x)\in B$ since $B$ is symmetric, and hence $(y,x) \in A\cup B$ and we are done.

I think this was essentially the proof you were going for. I don't think you needed $C=A\cup B$ (I assume this is what you meant), or indeed even to give a name like $c$ to $(x,y)$. Just clutters the proof because you eventually have to unfold these names again anyway.